# Creating equivalent impedance for given measured frequency response (that does not involve blind trial-and-error)

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, passive-networks

I have a measured frequency response and I would like to create an equivalent impedance model for it.

I start with a parallel RLC and then add series R and series L to the elements. I blindly tune the elements to visually match the two.

However, this is time consuming and I am never able to properly match the response. I don't even know what's the best procedure to select the model structure.

Attached is an example of measured frequency response (blue) and a model of

$$
Z_{\rm eq} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{sL + R_{s1}}+\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{sC}+sL_{s2}+R_{s2}}} .
$$

As can be seen, there is a slightly mismatch at the peak and the slope after the peak (30kHz to 1MHz) and at high frequencies (>3MHz).

[image]

Comment: You may be interested in [this page](https://www.sintef.no/projectweb/vectorfitting/). Otherwise, looking at the phase, you have more than a simple pole-zero in that area (see how the phase get's too close to -100 deg, passed -90).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you, that helps a lot and I can fit this well with 5-order approximation. The remaining question is whether there is a systematic way to come up with an equivalent passive network based on a pole/zero response (or state space model)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the computer to do it for you then try [this site](https://www.sintef.no/projectweb/vectorfitting/). Otherwise you can approximate it by inspection: there's a zero at 300~400 Hz, a complex pole at ~3 kHz (a critically damped or more would yield a more smooth peak), then a double complex zero at ~2 MHz, then it looks to be another double complex pole before the data is truncated. You could try to use the approach you used, but it looks like the response is periodic, as if after the end of data there would be another double complex zero, and then another double complex pole, and so on. This imples either sampling or reflections (more likely due to the damping). It would help to say what exactly you're trying to approximate, as pposed to showing a graph, because then there may be a better alternative. As it is it sounds too much like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/#) (probably the reason of the downvote).

If you wonder why the phase does not match the response at ~300 kHz, it's because the data shows the phase going very close to -100°, past -90° -- that implies a hidden pole, or bad data.